# OAUTH using PHP's PECL OAUTH - Cant use POST when using method getRequestToken()?

Tags: php, oauth, pecl

I'm using PECL OAuth when trying to authenticate to an API.

Sample Code:

```
<?php

$requestUri = 'http://openapi.lovefilm.com/oauth/request';

$consumerKey = 'MYCONSUMERKEY'; 
$consumerSecret = 'MYSECRET';

$oauth = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$oauth->setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
$oauth->setVersion('1.0');
$oauth->setTimestamp(mktime());


$oauth->enableDebug();

try
{
    $req = $oauth->getRequestToken($requestUri, 'oob');
    var_dump($req);
}
catch(OAuthException $e)
{
    print '<pre>';
    var_dump($e);

    var_dump($oauth->debugInfo);
}

?>
```

The specification they provide (http://developer.lovefilm.com/ - registration req) says I should POST a request similar to the one below:

> POST /oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
>     Host: openapi.lovefilm.com
>     Authorization: OAuth
>         oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fyour-service.com%2Fsuccess",
>         oauth_consumer_key="2blu7svnhwkzw29zg7cwkydn",
>         oauth_nonce="5f38dbc02a97567965f14d",
>         oauth_signature="sPSVmqN%2FXu9k0wlZxF0PqPZwYGo%3D",
>         oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
>         oauth_timestamp="1278499295",
>         oauth_version="1.0"

However when I use the the method:

```
$oauth->setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
```

The request that is generated is always a GET.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the [OAuth Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849), [the request for Temporary Credentials (AKA "Request Token")](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.1) and [the request for Token Credentials (AKA "Access Token")](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.3) MUST be submitted as an HTTP `POST` request, but the PECL OAuth extension seems to persistently use `GET` for `getRequestToken()` and `getAccessToken()`... by default.

There is [an `$auth_type` parameter to `OAuth::__construct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.construct.php) that accepts [one of the following values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.constants.php):

- `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION` -- Submit OAuth parameters in the  HTTP `Authorization` header of the request (and use a `GET` request by default).
- `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI` -- Submit OAuth parameters in the request URI (i.e. query params in a `GET` request).
- `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM` -- Submit OAuth parameters as part of the HTTP POST body (in a `POST` request).
- `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_NONE` -- Don't submit OAuth parameters at all, i.e. a "NoAuth" request (also `GET` by default).

From my experience, the `fetch()`, `getRequestToken()`, and `getAccessToken()` methods all respect this setting, [which can also be set with `OAuth::setAuthType()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.setauthtype.php) on an instance of the object. In practice, I set the auth type to `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM` while performing the dance, then reset to default -- `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION` -- to make resource requests.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit strange that they are asking specifically for POST when there is nothing in the post body in the example you gave!  Does it work when it's a GET request?  I'd be tempted to ping their tech support and ask what is going on there.  If POST required, you may have to assemble the request manually rather than using the PECL, which is quite possible but quite tedious.

Comment: 'The Service Provider documentation specifies the HTTP method for this request, and HTTP POST is RECOMMENDED. '

Comment: ^^ From the Oauth Spec on request tokens. (on a side note it seems pressing 'return' when typing in this box submits it). How annoying!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can fix this, is to use `OAuth::fetch` instead of `OAuth::getRequestToken` and `OAuth::getAccessToken`.

```
$oauth = new OAuth('consumer_key', 'consumer_secret');
$oauth->fetch(
    'https://example.com/oauth/request_token', 
    array(), 
    OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST
);
parse_str($oauth->getLastResponse(), $token_pair);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM` is only a workaround.

Pecl's oauth extension version 1.2.3 has [a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67650); `getRequestToken` and `getAccessToken` use GET requests instead of POST as the RFC wants.

You can work around this bug by passing `OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST` as 3rd parameter to `getRequestToken` and 4th parameter to `getAccessToken`. Yes, those parameters [are undocumented](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67649).

---

Version 1.2.4 of pecl/oauth will default to POST.